# move_uploaded_file and file_exists return true, can't view file in browser or FTP

Tags: php, file, post, ftp

The file does save to the target folder which I can access on the browser and FTP, because when I try to delete the directory it says that the folder is not empty.

I also know they're there, because when I do a scandir(), it lists all the files.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$device_name = str_replace(" ","_",strtolower($_POST["device_name"]));
$target_dir = getcwd()."/wedding/";
$target_dir = $target_dir.$device_name."_".time()."_".basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$arr = array();
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
    $arr["status"] = 1;
    $arr["result"] = "Photo Sent";
} else {
    $arr["status"] = 0;
    $arr["result"] = "Error Sending Photo";
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there where special characters in the filename.